# How to use both bootstrap js and jquery-ui js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have this code to use both boostrap js and jquery-ui functions.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script  type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $( "#spinner" ).spinner({ min: 0 });
  });

  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <label for="spinner">Select a value:</label>
  <input id="spinner" name="value">
  </body>
</html>
```

But this jquery-ui spinner doesn't work unless otherwise I remove bootstrap js below:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It seems there are conflicts. How to use both bootstrap js and avoide conflicts?

Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/joehark/pen/OJJmyzg

Comment: Simple answer is: don't. If you *really* have to do this, use custom builds of bootstrap and jQueryUI which remove the conflicting libraries (such as `tooltip()`,  `modal()` etc)

Comment: bootstrap don't have a spinner like jquery-ui?

Comment: True, but there are lots of other third party spinner libraries which don't cause conflicts

Comment: Could you please suggest some of those third party libs?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean loading spinner, I meant increasing/decreasing value spinner.

Comment: `<input type="number" />`

Comment: I meant could you suggest third party spinner lib as I cannot use jquery-ui? I mean the spinner for increasing/decreasing value not loading spinner.

Comment: I did, a `number` input does what you need. You can style that with CSS if required

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to create it with symfony form component? I did not see such type in their documentation.